# Http request connection timed out in google colab

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

We are writing code for yolo and upload integer to mcs lite on google colab. There is the code.
(Mcs lite github:https://github.com/MCS-Lite)

```
import http.client
import urllib
import json
import time
import sys   
import http
import socket

import urllib

print(http)
import http.client

if hasattr(http.client, 'HTTPSConnection'):
  print (type(http.client))

count_apple=2
  
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/lib/python2.7/bridge/') 

deviceId = ""
deviceKey = ""

def post_to_mcslite(payload):
    headers = {"Content-type": "text/csv", "deviceKey": deviceKey}
    not_connected = 1
    while (not_connected):
        try:
            conn = http.client.HTTPConnection("#IP")
            not_connected = 0
        except (http.client.HTTPException, socket.error) as ex:
            print("Error: %s" % ex)
            time.sleep(10) 

    conn.request("POST", "/api/devices/" + deviceId + "/datapoints.csv", payload, headers)
    response = conn.getresponse()
    print(( response.status, response.reason, payload, time.strftime("%c")))
    data = response.read()
    conn.close()

while True:
    apple = str(count_apple)
    appleString = "apple,," + apple
    payload =  appleString + "\n" 
    post_to_mcslite(payload)
    time.sleep(10)
```

This code are doing well and could run on visual code.
(Device Id ,Device key and IP had been filled.)
But it would wrong when it run on google colab, it will print out "conection timed out" and cannot closed. How could I do?

Comment: Hi, what URL (IP) are you trying to connect to?  Is it some private IP address (in your home network like 192.168.xxx.yyy) Or maybe a lookback address (127.0.0.1) ?  Such IP addresses cannot be accessed from outside network (which in this case is Google collab)?  Mind telling if the IP address is public or private ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: oh sorry. It is private IP address.

Comment: @return007 Is the problem related to the private IP? How should I change it?

Comment: @QLinkit I think you should be able to use ngrok.

Comment: @QLinkit I'm not sure why you're import `urllib` twice, and I can't see the endpoint variable you're using, if you can expose the full source without revealing the private IP it'll help to detect the issue, because recently I had a similar issue with google colab when sending a request to a website, the code was working fine before, and it works locally. I believe google is preventing requests for security reasons.